# How to sort employee by name , if we have duplicate names we sort them by last name and also how to sort by salary

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

**Suppose we have the following Employee class and `List` of `Employee`s:**

```
class Employee{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Double salary;

  Employee(Double salary, String firstName, String lastName){
         this.salary = salary;
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName; 
  }

// getter and setters


}

List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
employeeList.add(new Employee(40000d, "Abhijeet","Rakshit"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(30000d, "Sunil","Sawant"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(20000d, "Abhijeet", "Ranade"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(40000d, "Srikanth", "Ranka"));
```

I want to sort this by `first name`, then if equal, by `last name`, and then by `salary`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a comparator and the `list.sort` method.  subsequent `thenComparing` calls are only invoked if the previous comparison returned equal. I favored last name over salary for tie breakers.  They can be exchanged if required.

```
record Employee(double getSalary, String getFirstName, String getLastName) {
}

List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
employeeList.add(new Employee(40000, "Abhijeet","Rakshit"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(30000, "Sunil","Sawant"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(20000, "Abhijeet", "Ranade"));
employeeList.add(new Employee(40000, "Srikanth", "Ranka"));
        
employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
         .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName)
         .thenComparing(Employee::getSalary));
      

employeeList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Employee[getSalary=40000.0, getFirstName=Abhijeet, getLastName=Rakshit]
Employee[getSalary=20000.0, getFirstName=Abhijeet, getLastName=Ranade]
Employee[getSalary=40000.0, getFirstName=Srikanth, getLastName=Ranka]
Employee[getSalary=30000.0, getFirstName=Sunil, getLastName=Sawant]
```

Answer (score -2):

**In the below class there are two approach. one using stream.sorted and the other being list.sort method.

1. First approach will be useful when you dont want to modify the original collection and at the same time want to use stream operations like collect or filter.
2. Second approach is the faster approach and will always modify the original list**

````
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.stream.Collectors;
   
   public class SortEmployeesJava8 {
   
       public static void main(String args[]) {
   
           Comparator<Employee> employeeNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);
   
           Comparator<Employee> employeeLastNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getLastName);
   
           Comparator<Employee> employeeSalaryComparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary);
   
           SortEmployeesJava8 test = new SortEmployeesJava8();
   
           List<Employee> employeeList = test.getEmployeeList();
   
           System.out.println("Sort by Name Output \n");
   
   
           //List<Employee> sortedByNameEmployeeList =
                   employeeList
                   .sort(employeeNameComparator
                           .thenComparing(employeeLastNameComparator));
                   //.collect(Collectors.toList());
   
           employeeList.stream()
                   .forEach(e -> System.out.println("name : " + e.getName() + " " + e.getLastName()));
   
           System.out.println("\n Sort by Salary Output \n");
   
           List<Employee> sortedBySalaryEmployeeList = employeeList.stream()
                   .sorted(employeeSalaryComparator)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
   
           sortedBySalaryEmployeeList.stream()
                   .forEach(e -> System.out.println("name : " + e.getName() + " " + e.getLastName()+" Salary :"+e.getSalary()));
   
           employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName)
                   .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName)
                   .thenComparing(Employee::getSalary));
   
           System.out.println("\n Sort by using sort function of list ->Output \n");
   
           employeeList.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println("name : " + e.getName() + " " + e.getLastName()+" Salary :"+e.getSalary()));
   
   
       }
   
       class Employee {
           Double salary;
           String name;
   
           String lastName;
   
           Employee(Double salary, String name, String lastName) {
               this.salary = salary;
               this.name = name;
               this.lastName = lastName;
           }
   
           public Double getSalary() {
               return this.salary;
           }
   
           public void setSalary(Double salary) {
               this.salary = salary;
           }
   
           public String getName() {
               return this.name;
           }
   
           public void setName(String name) {
               this.name = name;
           }
   
           public String getLastName() {
               return lastName;
           }
   
           public void setLastName(String lastName) {
               this.lastName = lastName;
           }
   
       }
   
       public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
           List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
           employeeList.add(new Employee(40000d, "Abhijeet", "Rakshit"));
           employeeList.add(new Employee(30000d, "Sunil", "Sawant"));
           employeeList.add(new Employee(20000d, "Abhijeet", "Ranade"));
           employeeList.add(new Employee(40000d, "Srikanth", "Ranka"));
           return employeeList;
       }
   
   
   }

   
       
   ```
       
   Sort by Name Output 
   
   name : Abhijeet Rakshit
   name : Abhijeet Ranade
   name : Srikanth Ranka
   name : Sunil Sawant
   
    Sort by Salary Output 
   
   name : Abhijeet Ranade Salary :20000.0
   name : Sunil Sawant Salary :30000.0
   name : Abhijeet Rakshit Salary :40000.0
   name : Srikanth Ranka Salary :40000.0
   
    Sort by using sort function of list ->Output 
   
   name : Abhijeet Rakshit Salary :40000.0
   name : Abhijeet Ranade Salary :20000.0
   name : Srikanth Ranka Salary :40000.0
   name : Sunil Sawant Salary :30000.0
       ```
````

Comment: @WJS added your solutions as well, Thanks

Comment: I am trying to show ways of sorting here one using Comparator using sorted method on the stream and sort method directly called on list